# Modifying VehicleRoutingSolutionPainter.java in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

I tried modifying the VehicleRoutingSolutionPainter.java file in Optaplanner to display some other information too. However, building using Maven by executing mvn -DskipTests clean install throws following build error:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.15:check  on project optaplanner-examples: Failed during checkstyle execution

I then removed the edits I made to the java file. However, it still throws the same error. How do I make modifications to the java file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) is (packaged into) a Maven plugin used for checking code formatting issues -- OptaPlanner uses it in order for the code to look uniform all across the code base. You have two options on how to proceed:

- If you just want to make edits for your own purpose (and don't care about code formatting, I suggest out-commenting the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` in the main OptaPlanner `pom.xml` file (currently [lines 83-171](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/pom.xml#L83) in the file).
- Or, you can fix the formatting errors that checkstyle reports (see the checkstyle log and/or the lines below the error you posted in the console). You will have to do this if you want your changes to get merged back into OptaPlanner source code.

The reason why when you reverted the changes checkstyle was still unhappy is, that you probably left in some excessive whitespace, or failed to add a new line at the end of the file, or something similar.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot, oskopek!!